# Constructing an HTTP POST request using Curl and Postman

Tags: post, curl, http-post, postman

I have been using curl & Postman on Chrome to send http POST requests with one variable to an simple HTTP server I have running and I have noticed that they construct the requests slightly differently. Apologies if I might have used any incorrect terminology in constructing the question - I'm still learning this stuff.

Using Postman, the request is constructed by putting a '?' between the resource name and the variable. E.g.

```
http://192.168.0.2:9999/1/command?a=b
```

However, the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.0.2:9999/1/command --data a=b
```

does not put a '?' between the resource name and the variable.

The result is that the HTTP server interprets the requests differently.

In the first case, the body of the request is empty and in the second case the body contains a=b.

Which version is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POST` requests post data as part of the request body and `GET` requests via URL parameters. If you choose the `form data` option in `postman` you can pass it the same way (request body) in `postman` as well. [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) may be worth reading.

Comment: Thanks for the help YSU. I was putting the data in the wrong place using postman which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: **`curl --user admin:admin \
 --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
 --header "Accept: application/json" \
 --request POST \
 --data '{"short_description":"Test with CURL"}' \`** What should i need to do in postman to add the "--user admin:admin"

Comment: @09Q71AO534 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529379/how-to-stimulate-curl-request-to-a-request-using-postman

Answer (score 9):

Constructing curl , python request , using HTTP POST

1. Open postman client and click on code [Below save button ] refer snapshot .[image: Click on save button]
2. when click on code another window appears . refer snapshot .[image: change http post to curl]
3. similarly you can generate various other request [curl , python ,java , php ] refer snapshot

[image: generate code snippets]

You can refer below link 
http://jmeterblogb.blogspot.in/2016/11/constructing-curl-from-python-http-php.html