# How to stimulate cURL request to a request using postman

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following cURL request to localhost which runs fine:

```
curl -u admin:e4d4face52f2e3dc22b43b2145ed7c58ce66e26b384d73592c -d "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"feed.list\", \"id\": 1}" http://localhost/minifluxR/jsonrpc.php
```

But when I send the same request using Postman instead of cURL, I am getting:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"}}
```

In Postman I used a `GET` request and sent the following as headers:

```
url:http://localhost/minifluxR/jsonrpc.php
username:admin
api_token:e4d4face52f2e3dc22b43b2145ed7c58ce66e26b384d73592c
method: feed.list
```

The following is the PHP function I am trying to trigger:

```
$server = new Server;

$server->authentication(array(
    \Model\Config\get('username') => \Model\Config\get('api_token')
));

// Get all feeds
$server->register('feed.list', function () {
    return Model\Feed\get_all();
});
```

Please help me to correct these errors.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When using cURL, the `-u` [option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) (or `--user`) is used to supply the credentials for [HTTP Basic authentication](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Basic_Authentication). This sets the `Authorization` header to contain the [necessary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) to authenticate with the server.

<sub><sup>These steps apply to Postman's [packaged app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). For steps for the legacy app, view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28529598/3) of revision this answer.</sup></sub>

To use HTTP Basic authentication as you were in your cURL command, click the <kbd>Authorization</kbd> tab and enter your credentials. Clicking <kbd>Update Request</kbd> will add the necessary `Authorization` header for you.

---

[image: Postman's Authorization tab]

---

[image: Postman's Headers tab]

---

To submit the JSON data in the same way that you did with cURL, use a `POST` request, select <kbd>raw</kbd> under the <kbd>Body</kbd> tab, and enter your data like so:

---

[image: Postman's Body tab]

---

To debug this I used [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - a free web debugging proxy.

I used cURL's [`--proxy`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x) option to make it send its requests through Fiddler like so:

```bsh
curl \
--proxy http://localhost:8888 \
-u foo:bar \
-d "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"feed.list\", \"id\": 1}" \
http://localhost
```

Now that the request goes through Fiddler, I can select it from the session list, and use the "raw" inspector to see the raw request:

---

[image: Fiddler's "raw" inspector]

---

This shows me that the cURL is making a `POST` request with HTTP Basic authentication and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content. This type of data normally consists of keys and values, such as `foo=bar&hoge=fuga`. However, this cURL request is submitting a key without a value. A call to `var_dump($_POST)` will yield the following:

---

[image: var_dump output]

---

With a `=` at the end of the data (like so: `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "feed.list", "id": 1}=`) the `var_dump` will yield the following:

---

[image: var_dump output]

---

However, it seems that JsonRPC will use `file_get_contents('php://input')` in your case. This returns the data that was submitted with the request, including a `=`, if the data ends with it. Because it will try to parse the input data as a JSON string, it will fail if the string ends with a `=`, because that would be invalid JSON.

Using the [FoxyProxy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/foxyproxy-standard/gcknhkkoolaabfmlnjonogaaifnjlfnp) extension for Chrome, I created a proxy configuration for Fiddler (`127.0.0.1:8888`), which allowed me to easily debug the data being sent by Postman's `POST` request. Using `x-www-form-urlencoded` with a key of `foo` with no value, the data sent was actually `foo=`, which would result in your JSON string being invalid.

However, using "raw" input will allow for the specified data to be sent without a `=` being added to the end of it, thus ensuring the data is valid JSON.

Comment: @user2198400 I have updated my answer to respond to your query about using "raw" data. I don't know about doing the UTF-8 response. You should probably ask a new question for that.

Comment: what about pam authentication ? i am trying to simulate the following curl command:
```
curl --no-check-certificate https://localhost:8000/login \
        -d username=myusername \
        -d password=mypassword \
        -d eauth='pam'
```
I have added them as params but is not working

Answer (score 1):

Curl is using HTTP Basic authentication by default. Your headers set in Postman are something different. Try using Basic Auth in Postman. It is in top panel, you fill in username and password and authorization header will be generated.